# Pandas DataFrame - Filling a repeating null value with a preceding none-null value

Tags: python, pandas

How do I fill repeating null values with a preceding non-null value?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a','a', None, 'b', None, None])
```

For instance, the data frame above would be populated as:

> ['a','a','a','b','b','b']

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [df.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with the `ffill` method, as follows:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

**Example:**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['a','a', None, 'b', None, None])
>>> df.fillna(method='ffill')
   0
0  a
1  a
2  a
3  b
4  b
5  b
```

Comment: If if helped, you should accept (click the green check), by the answer.